# LOTKeypath not working in ios but working fine in Android

Tags: android, ios, dynamic, lottie

I try to change the colors of a lottie files in iOS.

In Android this works fine:

```
lottieAnimationView.addValueCallback(new KeyPath("foreground", "**"), LottieProperty.COLOR_FILTER, new LottieValueCallback(colorFilterForeground));
```

How to translate this to iOS objecive c?

```
LOTKeypath *keypath = [LOTKeypath keypathWidhKeys:@"foreground", @"**", nil];
LOTColorValueCallback *colorCallback = [LOTColorCallback withCGColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColoer};
[lottieAnimation setValueDelegate:colorCallback forKeypath:keypath];
```

The above does not work, the color is not changed.

I work with exactly the same lottie.json on Android and iOS.

Best Regards
Jochen